# Volume of a spherical tetrahedron

Tags: spherical-geometry

In the paper [Jun Murakami, *The volume formulas for a spherical tetrahedron*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2584) a formula for the volume of a spherical tetrahedron is given. I am trying to work through the details for the specific example where the dihedral angles are $\theta_1=\pi/4$, $\theta_2=\pi/4$, $\theta_3=\pi/4$, $\theta_4=\pi/6$, $\theta_5=\pi/6$ and  $\theta_6=\pi/6$. I get lost in a sea of root threes. Could someone help ?

Comment: While "spherical triangle" has a clear meaning (at least when three points are given within the same hemisphere of a sphere), I'm not certain what "spherical tetrahedron" should mean.  Four points on a sphere might be considered to "enclose" the entire sphere, for example (and give a spherical volume).

Comment: From the abstract *spherical tetrahedron, which is in a $3$-dimensional spherical space of constant curvature $+1$*

Comment: What exactly is it you want to know?

Comment: What is $q_0$, $q_1$, $q_2$ and $z_0$ would be a good start ... thank you Sigur for sorting the link.